# FileInputStream; Why can FileInputStream become an integer, does it have any meaning?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I'm studying java in a certain website and I found this

```
 import java.io.*;
public class CopyFile {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {  
      FileInputStream in = null;
      FileOutputStream out = null;

      try {
         in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
         out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");

         int c;
         while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
         }
      }finally {
         if (in != null) {
            in.close();
         }
         if (out != null) {
            out.close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What is the meaning of `c = in.read()) != -1`?Why can it be an integer?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) should clear all your confusion. What did you expect `read()` to do?

Comment: It reads a byte, which is positive, but can also return -1 if no bytes are read. See the javadoc at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FileInputStream` is a stream of bytes.

When you call `FileInputStream.read()` it return a `byte` from the stream or return -1 if reach end of stream.

When you write: `c = in.read()) != -1`,

- a `byte` is read from stream, widening as `int`, assign back to `c` and
- a check is made to see if a byte is read successfully by comparing the returned value with `-1`;

Comment: except -1 value, is there any value else like +1 or 0 and if there is any please explain it too.

Comment: The return value will be -1 if reach end of stream or any positive integer

Answer (score 0):

You used the method `FileInputStream.read()` ([Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read--) ) which reads a `byte` from a file

---

And `((c = in.read()) != -1)` does 2 things

- get the value of `in.read()` and store it in `c` (`byte` convert to `int`)
- check if `c` is different of `-1` (if equals to `-1` it means end of file)

So there is no `FileInputStream` becomes an `int`